# Stuck on generics and interfaces. Need solution based on code, maybe redesign of interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, service-locator

This is part of my code which I need help with:

```
// simple service locator
public class ServiceManager<TSvc> : IServiceManager<TSvc> where TSvc: class, IService
{
   private Dictionary<object, TSvc> services;

   public void RegisterService(TSvc service)
    {
        // omitted code here
        this.services.Add(service.GetType(), service); // dictionary
    }
    public T GetService<T>() where T : TSvc
    {
        T result = default(T);

        TSvc bufResult = null;
        if (this.services.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out bufResult))
            result = (T)bufResult;

        return result;
    }
    public TSvc GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        TSvc result = null;

        this.services.TryGetValue(serviceType, out result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then my domain interfaces:

```
public interface IItem
{
   string Name { get; set; }
}
public interface IRepository<TModel> where TModel : IItem
{
    new IEnumerable<TModel> GetItems();
    void InsertItem(TModel item);
    void UpdateItem(TModel item);
    void DeleteItem(TModel item);
}
public interface IService<TModel> where TModel : IItem
{
    IRepository<TModel> Repository { get; }
}
```

Then some of my domain classes:

```
public class Book: IItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class BookRepo: IRepository<Book>
{
    new IEnumerable<Book> GetItems();
    void InsertItem(Book item);
    void UpdateItem(Book item);
    void DeleteItem(Book item);
}
public class BookService: IService<Book>
{
    IRepository<Book> IService<Book>.Repository { get { return this.Repository; } }
    BookRepo Repository { get; set;} 
}
```

Now, if I am interested to use 'BookService' and do something with it, I could get it from service locator like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var bookService = serviceManager.GetService<BookService>();
    bookService.Repository.Insert(new Book()); 
}
```

But the problem is that the type of the service is known only at runtime (eg. selection from combobox). So, how would DoSomething method look like?

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var typeOfService = combobox.SelectedValue.GetType(); // cbx of services
    // ??? make use of serviceManager and typeOfService to get appropriate 'service'
    service.Repository.Insert(/*new IITem here*/);
}
```

Also, I would like to know how would you connect `IService` to `IService<TModel>`... it could even get to the solution, but I have no idea how. My `IService` interface is blank for the moment...

I would really appreciate your time. Please let me know if there is something unclear! Thank you!

**Update:** Based on your answers, I guess the reflection part could be involved (something like NSGaga pointed out), but still, without connecting `IService` and `IService<TModel>` I cannot achieve what I want. Who has any idea how to redesign this?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using an existing Dependency Container such as Ninject or Unity as opposed to building your own?

Comment: @Kenneth: The reason of learning would suffice? :) Is a good opportunity to learn manipulating interfaces and use generics

Comment: OK, understandable! I just thought that if you were after just a working solution as fast as possible I'd point you to one of the frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (typing from my head, so you'd need to check the syntax details - but should give you the direction - or I'll add on later)

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ServiceManager).GetMethod("GetService");
MethodInfo methodInfoGeneric = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeOfService });
methodInfoGeneric.Invoke(serviceManager, new object[] { });
```

Comment: So, reflection way... is really good to know such details... Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome Cristi - there is no other way to 'move' from `Type` into a 'strong typed` world.

Comment: btw, I still need somehow a connection between IService and IService<TModel>, otherwise it cannot work. How would my IService look like?

Comment: could you just add some details (what you want exactly, small example) - if you want to get a generic type IService<some type> - then it's similar you just use `typeof(IService<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type });` but I don't see that you need that. Do you have some inheritance issues there? Post some more and I'll look into it

Comment: If you see the ServiceManager<TSvc> declaration, TSvc: IService, but all my actual services are implementing IService<TModel>, so, yes, I think I am stuck with this inheritance. Don't know how to achieve it best.

Comment: np - I like when you said 'the reason of learning' :). Anyway this is too much work :) - your service manager and overall is all messed up. I'd have to rewrite it :). Anyway you could take a look at this post of mine - which is a bit similar (yet different - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687981/c-sharp-generics-interfaces-returning-different-types-based-on-the-class. Maybe if you'd like to open a new question - with the emphasis on the design, as it's entirely different (and a bigger issue), and close this one - just @ me here and I'll try to write something.

Comment: Your link is pretty close indeed with what I have in mind. And very nice stuff with IRepo<out T> there. My problem is that I need T here to be 'in' and 'out' (due to Get & Insert/Update)... hmm

Comment: btw, you said my design is messed up, could you point out at least the big points?

Comment: I will Cristi, at the end of the day, have lot of work today - yes you need both in/out. You can always 'reduce' the interface to mere basics. But there are better ways I think (need to look closely) - as many said, some DI/IOC does that for you, it's not simple stuff - I'll get back to you.

Comment: I tried your piece of code above but I can't figure it out how to get the result as the type I need, since Invoke returns object and don't know how to cast to the type I need, since it should be at runtime.

Comment: yes I figured that out when I tried to untie your design- that's where the problem is. You'd need to use something like `typeof(IService<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type });` - then invoke - but you don't have best interfaces set up. And it's better to minimize reflection -and make interfaces work for you. But you don't have that as it is. I'll try to post another answer here (maybe even another Q/A which you point to here or something), as soon as I manage, today/tomorrow - I'll at least give you some pointers.

Comment: yeah, is exactly what I thought from the beginning... a good design of interfaces should solve the problem, but don't know how :(

Answer (score 2):

To call a generic method where the type is only known at runtime requires using reflection.

For example, in your last code sample, you rightly imply that you can't call `GetService<BookService>`, but you are still adding `new Book()` to the service.  You would also have to use reflection to instantiate the new object, because, again, you don't know the type at compile time.  So you would need to use reflection at least three times: Once to call the method that returns the service, once to create the new object, and once to call the insert method on the service.

You can isolate some of this complexity with [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).  For example, create a generic method like this:

```
void CreateNewObject<T>() where T : new()
{
    var service = GetServiceFor<T>();
    service.Repository.Insert(new T());
}
```

Now, you only need to use reflection once, to call that method, instead of three times.

Comment: Very good and interesting points! Yes, sorry about that "new Book()" (copy-paste)... and I guess the reflection part I could get it from 'NSGaga'